# Can I install Sql Server 2008 on the same machine where Sql Server 2005 already installed

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, side-by-side

I have Sql Server 2005 Express installed on my computer, and I want to install Sql Server 2008 Express as well. What should I consider before doing this additional installation?

thanks.
bk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should be fine together, just make sure they are using different ports (the default is 1433) if they are communicating over TCP/IP. Why do you need both versions?

Comment: I need both versions since the Sql Server 2008 is so new for me. I was a little bit late to know all about the new features. 

- Now, I installed both versions. There was an error while installing the Sql Server 2008. I solved it with updating the Visual Studio 2008 to VS 2008 Sp1.

Now everything is allright. Thanks

Regards
Bk